# Using RequireJS with AngularJS. Problems loading AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, requirejs

I am creating a NodeJS app which uses AngularJS for it's front-end. I am Also using RequireJS to load in the JS dependencies and then instantiate the Angular app. Here is what I am trying to do:

Within my HTML file (written in Jade) I include the RequireJS files and then call the RequireJS config using the 'data-main' attribute:

```
doctype html
    html
        head
            title= title
            link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        body
            block content

        script(type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/main.js")
```

My main.js file looks as follows:

```
"use strict";

function(require) {
    require(['/assets/requiredPathsAndShim.js'], function(requiredPathsAndShim) {
        require.config({
            maps : {
                // Maps
            },
            paths : requiredPathsAndShim.paths,
            shim : {
                // Modules and their dependent modules
            }
        });

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['appNameInHere']);
    });
})(require);
```

I have an external file which contains an object with my routes '/assets/requiredPathsAndShim.js' and it looks like follows:

```
"use strict";

(function(define) {
    define([], function() {
        return {
            paths : {
                'angular' : '/bower_components/angular/angular'
            }
        };
    });
})(define);
```

I will add that my NodeJS/Express app has the 'bower_components' folder set to serve static files and this is working fine.

Whenever I try and instantiate the AngularJS app using the 'angular.bootstrap...' method it tells me Angular is not defined. I can't see why this is happening and haven't been able to figure it out yet. O can't see any problem with my routes to the Angular files. Can anyone see or suggest why this may be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to crack it! I had to place the 'angular.bootstrap' call in a callback function of the require.config method as the app was trying to call AngularJS before it had been defined.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.